# Visual Studio 2010 not recognisng .cshtml files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I recenetly reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 and since doing so I can not figure out how to get it to recognise .cshtml files again... I tried installing MVC 3 but it said it was already installed, basically when I open the .cshtml files in Visual Studio they have no code high lighting or intelli sense.

Any sugestions?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to reinstall the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 tools.

You might just be able to do a repair install of MVC 3. If that doesn't work, I'd uninstall MVC 3 (making sure it removes the tools too) and re-install them both.

Comment: Follow these steps to uninstall allMvc components: http://drew-prog.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-3.html

Comment: As of the April 2011 release you cannot do a repair and must do an uninstall and fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

And even if you install it right, there is no support for a visual editor.  It will remain in code view.  However, with MVC3 and beyond, there is good support for intellisense.